# Android: custom view layout for SectionIndexer and disabling SectionIndexer on the fly

Tags: android, list, listadapter

1. Is it possible to use custom view as a section indexer? I.e. make it more transparent and use images instead of characters?
2. Is it possible to enable/disable SectionIndexer popup on demand without disabling FastScroll feature?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. To achieve this do not use SectionIndexer. Create a CustomAdapter by extending BaseAdapter. There make an entry for image view. if the condition is satisfied, then show the image view; otherwise do not show the image view. You have to set the condition. Better create a hashmap, and store `position` as key and `imageview visible or not` as value.